# Get only dataValues from sequelize raw query instead of Model instance

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize and using raw query to  get the datas from table. But I'm getting all of the model instances while I only need the dataValues.
My setup looks like this:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  username: process.env.PGUSER,
  password: process.env.PGPASS,
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  port: process.env.PGPORT,
  dialect: "postgres"
});

getPostGres: () => {
    return sequelize;
  }
```

and the way I'm querying the database looks like this:

```
let messageRatingsArr = await getPostGres().query(
    `SELECT mr.support_email, mr.support_name,
    (select count(mrn."chatId") as total FROM message_ratings as mrn WHERE mrn."ratingType"='NEGATIVE' and mr.support_email = mrn.support_email) as negative,
 (select count(mrp."chatId") as total FROM message_ratings as mrp WHERE mrp."ratingType"='POSITIVE' and mr.support_email = mrp.support_email) as positive,
 (select count(mrm."chatId") as total FROM message_ratings as mrm WHERE mrm."ratingType"='MIXED' and mr.support_email = mrm.support_email) as mixed,
 (select count(mru."chatId") as total FROM message_ratings as mru WHERE mru."ratingType"='NEUTRAL' and mr.support_email = mru.support_email) as neutral
      FROM message_ratings mr 
      WHERE mr."createdAt" >= '${properFromDate}' AND mr."createdAt" <= '${properToDate}'
     group by mr.support_email, mr.support_name 
     limit ${args.count} offset ${args.offset} `,
    {
      model: MessageRatingPG,
      mapToModel: true
    }
  );
  let messageRatings = messageRatingsArr.map(item=>{
    return item.dataValues;
  })
  let result = connectionFromArray(messageRatings, args);
  result.totalCount = messageRatings.length;
  return result;
```

As you can see, since I'm mapping the data from the query which has all kinds of stuff like dataValues, _options, isNewRecord etc., looping through the array if I have a large data set isn't efficient, so what can I do to only get the dataValues?

Answer (score 1):

From https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html:

> In cases where you don't need to access the metadata you can pass in a query type to tell sequelize how to format the results. For example, for a simple select query you could do:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(users => {
    // We don't need spread here, since only the results will be returned for select queries
  })
```

Now, looking at your code, and comparing with the next paragraph in the docs:

> A second option is the model. If you pass a model the returned data will be instances of that model.

```
// Callee is the model definition. This allows you to easily map a query to a predefined model
sequelize
  .query('SELECT * FROM projects', {
    model: Projects,
    mapToModel: true // pass true here if you have any mapped fields
  })
  .then(projects => {
    // Each record will now be an instance of Project
  })
```

I'd suggest removing from your original code, the following:

```
{
  model: MessageRatingPG,
  mapToModel: true
}
```

and replacing it with `{ type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your query the attribute `raw`. From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#raw-queries)

> Sometimes you might be expecting a massive dataset that you just want
>   to display, without manipulation. For each row you select, Sequelize
>   creates an instance with functions for update, delete, get
>   associations etc. If you have thousands of rows, this might take some
>   time. If you only need the raw data and don't want to update anything,
>   you can do like this to get the raw data.

```
 Project.findAll({ where: { ... }, raw: true })
```

Comment: OP clearly uses `.query()` to write out his raw query. This is incompatible with `Model.findAll()` which you propose.